# Fix warning in cast List<ArrayObject>

Tags: java, eclipse

How could i fix this warning?

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from `List` to `List<ArrayObject>`

```
List<List<ArrayObject>> detailList = search.getDetails(
    (List<ArrayObject>) ((DefaultListBackedValueList) request.getAttribute(LIST)).getList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `getAttribute()` is not parameterized method and returns `Object` there is no way to fix the warning. You have to suppress it.

When I have to suppress warning I typically try to decrease the scope of suppression. In your case you can suppress warning on current statement or create special method that returns `List<ICTWeb>` and suppress warning there. You can also write a short comment that describes why do you suppress warning.

BTW I have no idea why are you using double casting `(List<ArrayObject>) ((DefaultListBackedValueList)`. I believe it is no necessary.

Comment: It is a older application that i have to fix.